# Google Geocoding API: number of results

Tags: rest, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Is there a way to increase the number of results returned by Google Geocoding API. Right now the default seems to be 10, however it does not seem to include the intended result.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample request that demonstrates your issue and explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Getting more results from the Geocoding API is not necessarily a solution. And no, can't get more.

Instead, you may want to use the [Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete), or the [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) in the Maps JavaScript API. Specially when bound to a map, it makes it much easier for users to find places.